# Select JFXCombobox item and send to new Combobox

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, java-8, jfoenix

I use the JFoenix library for my Comboboxes.

'***boxLeague.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> boxTeams.setItems(listPremierLeague));***' will put all the text to the boxTeams Combobox when anything is selected from boxLeague Combobox, but what I want to do is that when a specific item is selected in boxLeague, then fill the other combobox.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
private JFXComboBox<String> boxLeague;

@FXML
private JFXComboBox<String> boxTeams;

@FXML
private JFXComboBox<String> boxPlayers;


ObservableList<String> listLeagues = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        "Bundesliga", "La Liga", "Ligue 1", "Premier League", "Serie A", "Champions League", "Europa League");

ObservableList<String> listPremierLeague = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        "Arsenal", "Bournemouth", "Brighton", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton");




@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    boxLeague.setItems(listLeagues);
    boxLeague.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> boxTeams.setItems(listPremierLeague));
}
```

}

Comment: You only have one list of teams in the example, am I right in thinking that you'll have a list of teams for each league in `listLeagues`?

Comment: Yes, I have one list of teams in listPremierLeague for now and the listLeagues are all the leagues that will be used. Im going to make for example listBundesliga and that will have other teams and it will be called again from listLeagues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside of your listener you need to find out which league was selected an set the items of the `boxTeams` accordingly.

```
boxLeague.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
  (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> { 
      if (newValue.equals("Premier League")) {
          boxTeams.setItems(listPremierLeague));
      } // else if ... (or use a switch-case here)
  }
);
```

Note that this could be improved further if you wouldn't use `String`s for the leagues and teams, but create your own classes.

Comment: Thanks Markus K, I will make every leage and teams to classes but wanted to understand how a if-statement would work in lambda expressesion.
Another problem here is that when I choose Premier League then the teams popup, but if I change to Bundesliga then the teamsof Premierleague will still be there. But that would work with a else-if that pointed to setItems(null) or ("") I believe